# Get missing index statistics in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, sql-server-2014

For example consider a database that has many SP and many query execute on it using ORMs. It's very time consuming that check every SP or profile all queries that `ORMs` generate for performance and missing index problem.

Is there any way to get missing index statistics for all SP and queries?

thanks